# Using curl to https gets 403 response

Tags: curl, https, proxy

I can't connect to foreign site because of the Great Wall!
So I use a proxy which works well.
However, when I use brew to install automake, I get the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYFsM.png)

Clearly, it fails when download automake-1.15.el_capitan.bottle.2.tar.gz using curl. Then I try to download using command line. It still fails.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mPC4.png)

However, I could download the file using my chrome by setting the porxy with SwitchySharp.

So, could someone explains the reason?
BYW, the command without "--proxytunnel" still fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think I catch the answer.
The version of nss on proxy Server is low.
For details, see https://serverfault.com/questions/606135/curl-35-ssl-connect-error